# Extracting data from vector tile package (.vtpk) using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-tiles, extract, tile-package

I have been provided with 1m land contours in a vector tile package (.vtpk). It is 14GB.

Is it possible to extract the data from the .vtpk into a geodatabase?

I have access to ArcGIS Pro 2.2, ArcMap 10.6 and QGIS 3.2.0.

I have tried the "Extract Package" tool in ArcGIS Pro. However, it kept crashing.

Is there a more suitable tool or should I keep trying with the extract package tool?

The contours are required to be in a shapefile in order to be used in acoustic modeling software.

Comment: 14GB to a shapefile? Be sure to consider the inherent limitations of that format when trying to create a data set of that magnitude (if expecting to have one single shapefile). Specifically the .dbf limits. Luckily with a vtpk it has multiple scales of that same dataset and styling information that could be ignored during the conversion.

Comment: What are the precise symptoms that you describe as "crashing"?

Answer (score 2):

If ArcGIS Pro is crashing while opening the VTPK, there isn't anything you can do. I'd submit that to Esri Tech Support (or your Distributor if not in the USA).

As for what you're trying to do: extract contours from the VTPK to perform some analysis... you aren't going to have a lot of luck doing this. I'd head back to where ever you got the VTPK from and ask them for the source data either as a SHP, or fGDB, or some other spatial format. Vector Tiles are meant to visual the data; think of them as a conversion of the data. Some level of generalization happens to vector tiles (I *think* that the generalization is done on the client, but its very well possible that the generalization is baked into the VTPK data itself. Meaning, the 1m contours might not actually be 1m contours inside the package). There is no tool inside ArcGIS Pro to convert VTPK into "Data" that tools can make use of. (Other software packages *may* do this, but Pro, and specifically Extract Package will not turn the contents of VTPK into shp or fGDB data).

Note: You can try [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to try extracting the package, however, the contents of the package will not have data in a format like shapefile.

Comment: This says vtpk follows the mapbox spec.  https://blog.mapbox.com/mapbox-vector-tile-specification-adopted-by-esri-14138105872f

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS Pro VTPK follow the spec